# Two fragment using same adapter in TabLayout not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

Only the first fragment is populated with the image, the second fragment is blank. I am using the same adapter for both fragments. I am not sure where is the problem.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(PopularMoviesFragment.newInstance(SORT_POPULAR), "MOST POPULAR");
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(RatingMoviesFragment.newInstance(SORT_RATING), "TOP RATING");

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}

public void switchToDetail(Intent intent){
    startActivity(intent);
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
static class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

First fragment

```
public static PopularMoviesFragment newInstance(String sort) {
    PopularMoviesFragment fragment = new PopularMoviesFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("sort", sort);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sortOrder = getArguments().getString("sort");
    mContext = getActivity();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mPopularList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(POPULAR_LIST);
        for (Movie m : mPopularList) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate: " + m.getTitle());
        }
    } else {
        FetchPopularMovies pm = new FetchPopularMovies();
        pm.execute(SORT_POPULAR);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View pView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular_movies, container, false);

    mAdapter = new MoviePosterAdapter(mContext, mPopularList);

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) pView.findViewById(R.id.movies_progress_bar);
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) pView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return pView;
}
```

Second fragment

```
public static RatingMoviesFragment newInstance(String sort) {
    RatingMoviesFragment fragment = new RatingMoviesFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("sort", sort);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sortOrder = getArguments().getString("sort");
    mContext = getActivity();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Has saved instance");
        mRatingList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(RATING_LIST);
    } else {
        FetchRatingMovies rm = new FetchRatingMovies();
        rm.execute(SORT_RATING);
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rating_movies, container, false);

    ratingAdapter = new MoviePosterAdapter(mContext, mRatingList);

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.movies_progress_bar);
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(ratingAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

MoviePosterAdapter

```
public class MoviePosterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviePosterAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final String LOG_TAG = MoviePosterAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

final Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Movie> mDataset;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //public final View mView;
    public final ImageView mImageView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MoviePosterAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie> myDataset) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

public void setMoviesData(ArrayList<Movie> moviesData){
    mDataset = moviesData;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MoviePosterAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                        int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.movie_poster, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Movie mMovie = mDataset.get(position);

    //Creating URL for image
    final String POSTER_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
    final String SIZE_PATH = "w185";
    String IMG_PATH = mMovie.getImg();

    //Loading image using Glide
    Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
            .load(POSTER_BASE_URL + SIZE_PATH + IMG_PATH)
            .placeholder(R.color.grid_placeholder_bg)
            .into(holder.mImageView);

    holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", mMovie.getId());
            i.putExtra("title", mMovie.getTitle());

            if (mContext instanceof MainActivity) {
                MainActivity main= (MainActivity) mContext;
                main.switchToDetail(i);
            }
        }
    });
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}
```

}

Please help me!

EDIT: Both the arrays are not empty. Here is the issue I think, only one fragment gets populated, maybe because there is some problem with the adapter(not sure). If I try to stop first fragment to get populated(commenting out the notifyDatasetChanged()), then the second fragment works fine.

Comment: Please post relevant code here, Instead of giving link of the project. And also you haven't specify which fragment is first fragment and which fragment is second fragment.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Please post the code of MoviePosterAdapter

Comment: @Rehan I have added the code of MoviePosterAdapter

Comment: They all look fine. Please verify that you are not passing empty list to the adapter i.e. mPopularList or mRatingList are not empty

Comment: @Rehan I took the log. The list is not empty.

Comment: I hope you have checked both lists. If they aren't empty, then there should not be any issue. You need to look deeply in it and verify the data in the lists is correct so that there should not be any issue in loading too. If it's fine then do check the xml also. Still, if everything looks fine, then probably you'll have to wait for someone else to help you in this matter.

Comment: @Rehan I am sure both lists are not empty. Thanks. Then i have to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image wasn't populating in the second fragment because it was an issue with Glide library. Switched to Picasso. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and i found that everything is fine. I tried with dummy data so i am damn sure that the mistake is in your data or adapter where you are setting data. Just try once with dummy data so you will be more clear or if still you are getting blank screen then let me know.

Generally blank screen comes because of there is no data. so please check once..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed it. It was some issue with Glide library. So I switched to Picasso. Now its works fine.